# Парсинг html с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, html, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как спарсить строку из `html` файла такого вида, с помощью `regexp`:

```
<div> <h2> <span style="font-size: 12px; padding: 5px;">Hello!</span></h2> "variable string" <br /><br /> </div>
```

Под *"variable string"* предполагается какой-то текст произвольный (имя если быть точным).

```
myHttpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var readers = new StreamReader(myHttpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                // сайт-строка
                string html = readers.ReadToEnd();
```

Мой вариант реализации слишком "индусирован": сплитом разбиваю строку на массив строк без "лишних" символов, индентифицирую элемент содержащий "Hello!", по его номеру определяю номер следующего элемента (имя) и его уже вывожу.
Есть ещё кончено html agility pack для парсинга html в c#, но интересует именно регулярное выражение, т.к. с его помощью можно не тянуть целую библиотеку для пары строчек кода.

Задачу решил с помощью регулярного выражения (в комментарии ниже), но вот пример моего "парсинга", он более наглядный для начинающих вроде меня.

---

```
        // Строка для хранения результата
        string storageForResponse = "";
        // Читаем HTML-код сайта
        string html = readers.ReadToEnd();
        // Разбиваем строку на массив строк
        string[] words = html.Split(new[] { ' ', ',', ':', '?', '\n', '\t', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
        if (words[i] == "Hello!")
        {
        if (i < words.Length - 1)
        {
        storageForResponse += words[i + 1];
        }
        break;
        }
        }
        }
```

Comment: @grandpa а что случится страшного, если библиотеку все-таки подтянуть?

Comment: Думаю что ничего, но не представляю как с её помощью выцепить именно этот фрагмент (<div> тег без какого либо уникального имени)

Comment: Была у программиста проблема. Решил он её с помощью регулярных выражений. Теперь у него две проблемы. &copy;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нужно спарсить много данных из HTML\не получается вытянуть регулярками и нужен парсинг по DOM модели - то однозначно: https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Если дернуть нужно одну строчку - не вижу смысла подтягивать либу. Вот пример регулярки для выдергивания всех значений со страницы между тегами:

```
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

            // Регулярка
            string pattern = @"<div class=""date"">(?<val>.*?)<\/span>";
            RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline;
            Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
            Match match = regex.Match(HTML.ToString());
            string Result = "";

            while (match.Success)
            {
                result += match.Groups["val"].Value;
                match = match.NextMatch();
            }
```

Comment: > то однозначно: https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Я бы поспорил. [CsQuery][1] тоже хорош. И селекторы у него читабельнее и короче

[1]: https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery

Comment: Да, возможно, но htmlagilitypack есть и под WinRT - а это несомненный плюс.

Comment: Спасибо за пример регулярки, использую как шаблон в дальнейшем, задачу решил без регулярок и библиотек, всё таки "индусский" метод оказался наиболее подходящим.

Comment: Если будете пользоваться регулярками - сначала выводите разметку в richTextBox, у меня бывали случаи, когда через браузер стояли двойные кавычки, а get запросом - одинарные.

Answer (score 6):

HTML не парсится регулярными выражениями. В принципе. Пользуйтесь полновесным парсером. Если есть сомнения, подумайте, как вы собираетесь обрабатывать, например, комментарии. HTML entity. Незначимые пробелы. Вложенные теги.
Вот внеклассное чтение по теме.

Comment: @VladD, как всегда, отличное "внеклассное чтение".

А может и правда, что от популярности регулярок один лишь вред?

В самом деле, не учат же в автошколе [динамическому повороту](http://avtovaz.narod.ru/lesson/01.html).

Comment: @avp: Я считаю, что регулярки переоценены. Ну и вспомню ещё раз цитату jwz, которую привёл выше @Donil.

Регулярки есть фактически ещё один язык программирования, с достаточно сложным синтаксисом, практически не поддающийся разумной отладке. Поэтому его применение должно быть, как мне кажется, ограничено простейшими самоочевидными случаями.